# state value does not change when using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, path

well I have:

```
const [bgColor, setBgcolor] = useState(false);
```

and :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/SignUp') {
        setBgcolor(true);
    } else {
        setBgcolor(false);
    }
    console.log(bgColor)
    return () => {
        setBgcolor(false);
    }
}, [])
```

What I want to do : is when i reload the page or rerender the page i check the current pathname if it is equal to /Signup I set the bgColor to true but here at every time i reload give me false!

Comment: maybe you have typo problem in '/SignUp' . can u console.log(window.location.pathname)?

Comment: when i console.log(window.location.pathname) I get /SignUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [bgColor, setBgcolor] = useState(false);
const { pathname } = window.location;

 useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/SignUp') {
       setBgcolor(true);
   } else {
       setBgcolor(false);
   }
   console.log(bgColor)
   return () => {
       setBgcolor(false);
   }
 }, [pathname]);
```

Comment: still give me false

Comment: Can you please share a codesandbox for your use case so I can help better.

Comment: Also, You need to check bgColor outside this useEffect since useState updates the state in an async way so you won't get updated value inside useEffect.

Comment: ok I'll try this